# CSS opacity transitions

Tags: css, transition, opacity

I am trying to set the opacity of the selected image in my photo slider to 1. It works on hover, and I am sure that the active-thumbnail class is correctly assigned because when I try any other styling it works. Even if I set the opacity to something smaller than 0.6, it makes it more transparent. The only thing I can not make it do it have an opacity higher than 0.6.

It is probably something small and stupid, but I have been trying so many things, I do not know what to do anymore! Thanks in advance for any help!

```
.photo-thumbnail {
  width: 10%;
  margin: 2px;
  opacity: 0.6;
  transition: opacity 300ms ease-in;
}

.photo-thumbnail:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 300ms ease-in;
}

.active-thumbnail {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 300ms ease-in;
}
```

Comment: You have a typo in your css `transition` definition. Please RTM

Comment: Thank you for encouraging people to ask for help, the 3 transitions are the same, 2 work. So please explain where the typo is.

Comment: I'm very sorry for that, it was my bad (Didn't copy the code correctly). So you're trying to change the opacity of `.photo-thumbnail` to `.8` (for example) and it doesn't work?

Comment: No worries, happens to everyone! - Yes I want it back to 1, just like when you hover over it. It works on hover, but not when the active-thumbnail class is assigned

Comment: could you please create a reproducible example on JS Fiddle? just the basic HTML and JS to add class

Comment: It might be a dependency issue, maybe some code or other css is overriding your style. Can you please create a [mcve]

Comment: @CapitanFindus it is a React project, so I am not sure how to make that happen.. But the class is assigned correctly, every other styling that I want to apply works.

Comment: @AlonEitan I am trying to make something simple, but how can it be overwritten if it works when I want to make it more transparent?

Comment: That's what so strange about it, because it looks like it _should_ work while it doesn. Did you inspect the elements and check what is the `opacity` style of the elements on the page itself?

Comment: @AlonEitan it says that the opacity is 1 when I inspect it, no errors and not overwritten..

Comment: @Rianne can we have the `markup` part or a link to the actual site ?

Comment: @Gildas.Tambo I can give you the link to my github repo? https://github.com/RianneStreef/rest-template
It is a project where I am trying out different thing, this part is the photoSlider component 
Or I can try to deploy it on Netlify?

Comment: @Rianne  do you have anydesk or skype i can't start much with git.

Comment: I deployed the code on https://riannestreef.github.io/rest-template/, does that help?

Comment: @Rianne Now we have something to start with please make sure you add the `active-thumbnail ` class to the ` photo-thumbnail` grandparent on the click event.

Answer (score 0):

Having a look at your code, shows that you are applying the active class `active-thumbnail` on the image element.

Do it on the Grandparent element instead (which has the class `photo-thumbnail`).

```
.photo-thumbnail {
    width: 10%;
    margin: 2px;
    opacity: .6;
    transition: opacity .3s ease-in;
}
```

The end result shall look like this for the active `photo-thumbnail`

```
 class="photo-thumbnail active-thumbnail"
```

[image]

so you shall probably change this

```
className: "mySlides ".concat(g && g === A.id ? "active-thumbnail" : "")
```

To this in your `main.js` file

```
className: "photo-thumbnail ".concat(g && g === A.id ? "active-thumbnail" : "")
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, I am going to try this! Thank you! But in the mean time, I still don't get that it works when I want to set the opacity to 0, but not they other way around.. Anyways, I have never used .concat, so thanks for teaching me something new!

Comment: @Rianne that is the code from your project the compiled one check you javascript where you handeln the click event and just change  `mySlides` to `photo-thumbnail` that is all.